# Xamarin iOS Swift library .a error on Visual studio mac

Tags: ios, xamarin, swift4, static-libraries, visual-studio-mac

I have found some issue while run a iOS App on Xamarin iOS. Kindly help me to succeed.

[image]

I have tried to create a Xamarin iOS App. I have .a library. It contains NSObject class and single function.

```
import Foundation

@objc(CustomSwift)
class CustomSwift: NSObject {

    func getValue() -> String {
        return "Hi, This is a Custom swift.a"
    }
}
```

And I created a fat library by using

> lipo -create -output

[image]

I have imported .a library on Xamarin iOS Binding library project.

**ApiDefinition.cs**

```
using System;

using ObjCRuntime;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace CustomSwiftLibrary
{
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface CustomSwift
    {

        [Export ("getValue")]
        string Value { get; }
    }
}
```

And I call my .a library class on ViewController.cs

```
 CustomSwift customObject = new CustomSwift();
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(customObject.Value);
```

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/344688/#Comment_344688 maybe helpful.

Comment: Are you including the Swift frameworks (Xamarin does not directly support Swift-based binding libraries) : https://github.com/Flash3001/Xamarin.Swift